# Check if $2^n = O(n^2)$ , prove it by using induction on $(2^n / n^2) > n$

Tags: induction, asymptotics

I don't know how to solve by induction  $(2^n / n^2) > n$ to check if $2^n = O(n^2)$ . I know that
$2^n = O(n^2)$ will be false by using the big O definition, but I don't know how to prove it by using induction on  $(2^n / n^2) > n$. I don't even completely understand how the $(2^n / n^2) > n$ was created as it was already in the question.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3887405/what-is-the-limit-of-n1000-2n-and-why)

Answer (score 1):

$2^n = O(n^2)$ would mean that $\dfrac{2^n}{n^2} \longrightarrow 0$ when $n \longrightarrow \infty$, by unwrapping the big $O$ definition.

So all you need to show is that this ratio does not got to $0$ at $\infty$.

Can you see why this follows from $\dfrac{2^n}{n^2} > n$ ?

Comment: $2^n\in o(n^2)$ would mean that. The big-$O$ case can be refuted with a slight variant, e.g. by refuting the consequence $2^n\in o(n^3)$.

Comment: Yes, but the problem says to use the fact that $2^n/n^2 > n$